# show LOADING until page is completely loaded

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have this javascript:

```
function createRequestObject(){
    var req;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        //For Firefox, Safari, Opera
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject){
        //For IE 5+
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else{
        //Error for an old browser
        alert('Your browser is not IE 5 or higher, or Firefox or Safari or Opera');
    }
    //alert (req);
    return req;
}

//Make the XMLHttpRequest Object
var http = createRequestObject();

function sendRequestTwo(method, url, head1){
    head = head1
    if(method == "get" || method == "GET"){
        http.open(method,url);
        http.onreadystatechange = handleResponseTwo;
        http.send(null);

    }
}

var head; //divs name

function handleResponseTwo(){
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
        var response = http.responseText;
        if(response){  
            document.getElementById(head).innerHTML = response;
        }
    }      
}
```

This part

```
            document.getElementById(head).innerHTML = response;
```

pastes the result back to my page.
How can I show "Loading" Before the page is completely loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can print the **Loading** into the Head div at the time of `sendRequestTwo`

Comment: You should make sure that the Ajax response was returned correctly. If so the statement "document.getElementById(head).innerHTML = response" will replace the content of "loading"

Answer (score 3):

How about having a Div with your loading Html in the body like

```
<div id="loadingDiv" class="hiddenClass">Fancy rotating image goes here</div>
```

have a css class that says display:none; then you could use this before

```
http.onreadystatechange = handleResponseTwo;
var myDiv = document.getElementById('loadingDiv');
myDiv.className = "showClass";
```

then after

```
document.getElementById(head).innerHTML = response;
```

add

```
var myDiv = document.getElementById('loadingDiv');
myDiv.className = "hiddenClass";
```

All together

```
function createRequestObject(){
    var req;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
        //For Firefox, Safari, Opera
        req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if(window.ActiveXObject){
        //For IE 5+
        req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else{
        //Error for an old browser
        alert('Your browser is not IE 5 or higher, or Firefox or Safari or Opera');
    }
    //alert (req);
    return req;
}

//Make the XMLHttpRequest Object
var http = createRequestObject();

function sendRequestTwo(method, url, head1){
    head = head1
    if(method == "get" || method == "GET"){
        var myDiv = document.getElementById('loadingDiv');
        myDiv.className = "showClass";

        http.open(method,url);
        http.onreadystatechange = handleResponseTwo;
        http.send(null);

    }
}

var head; //divs name

function handleResponseTwo(){
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
        var response = http.responseText;
        if(response){  
            document.getElementById(head).innerHTML = response;
            var myDiv = document.getElementById('loadingDiv');
            myDiv.className = "hiddenClass";
        }
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the details of your HTML, but couldn't you just put loading in the tag that has an `id="head"`?

Then when you update the innerHTML, the loading would automatically be replaced. If you have more requirements, please describe.

Comment: That's pretty much how it is done, but the `response` is taking time to load; how can I check if it completely loaded?

Comment: To see if `response` is loaded, you just check whether `http.readyState==4`. But I think you are talking about something else. Is there something else that needs to load like images in the `response` HTML?